# How to show that this integral diverges or converges?

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to verify if the integral $$\int_1^{\infty}\ln((\exp(1/x)+(n-1))/n)dx, \;\;n>0$$

is convergent or divergent? I made some handy calculations but couldn't find any way for it. Please give me help.

Comment: Divergent. Hint: find a simple equivalent of the integrand at infinity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $e^{1/x}+(n-1)/n\geq e^{1/x}$ and so $\ln (e^{1/x}+(n-1)/n)\geq 1/x$. Hence the given integral is greater than or equal to $$\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x}dx=\lim_{x\to\infty}\ln x=\infty$$

Comment: Your first step is a nice trick. Thank you very much.

Comment: The idea is nice but the logarithm is not the one in the question hence its lower bound does not apply, as soon as $n\gt1$. (So much for the upvotes and for the acceptance 14 minutes after the answer is posted.)

Answer (score 3):

HINT: Besides to @pritman's answer; consider the integrand as $f(x)=\ln(1+\frac{e^{x^{-1}}-1}{n})$. I agree with @did that $f(x)=\ln(1+\frac{e^{x^{-1}}-1}{n})\sim\frac{1}{nx}$ when $n$ tends to infinity. Can you do the rest?